How to simulate AWS DynamoDB locally in python with moto 5
I want to make a class representing a dynamodb connection which I can use locally to mimic the behavior of DynamoDB without having to actually contact the  AWS service.
I want to use it during development (not just for running tests) and use that class for creating a table which exists during program execution, and make queries to it just as I would a real dynamo table with a real connection
I am using boto3 v1.34.162 and moto v5.0.15
So far, here is what I have come up with:
import boto3
from moto import mock_aws

@mock_aws
class MyDbClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        self.table_name = 'ExampleTable'
        self.create_table()
    
    def create_table(self):
        table_params = {
            'TableName': self.table_name,
            'KeySchema': [
                {'AttributeName': 'id', 'KeyType': 'HASH'},
            ],
            'AttributeDefinitions': [
                {'AttributeName': 'id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
            ],
            'ProvisionedThroughput': {
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 5,
            }
        }

        print(f"Creating table {self.table_name}...")
        self.dynamodb.create_table(**table_params)

        print(f"Waiting for table {self.table_name} to exist...")
        waiter = self.dynamodb.get_waiter('table_exists')
        waiter.wait(TableName=self.table_name)

        print(f"Table {self.table_name} is now active.")

        tables = self.dynamodb.list_tables()['TableNames']
        print("Existing tables:", tables)


    
    def put_item_in_table(self, item):
        self.dynamodb.put_item(
            TableName=self.table_name,
            Item={
                'id': {'S': item['id']},
                'name': {'S': item['name']},
                'description': {'S': item['description']}
            }
        )
    
    def get_item_from_table(self, key):
        response = self.dynamodb.get_item(
            TableName=self.table_name,
            Key={
                'id': {'S': key['id']}
            }
        )
        print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_client = MyDbClient()

    item_to_put = {
        'id': '123',
        'name': 'ExampleName',
        'description': 'This is a sample item'
    }
    db_client.put_item_in_table(item_to_put)
        
    key_to_get = {'id': '123'}
    db_client.get_item_from_table(key_to_get)


The @mock_aws decorator should be what I need, but when executing this I am getting the following error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the GetRoleCredentials operation: Not yet implemented when the program execution comes to the create_table call.
Here is the full stack trace as well:
(venv) ⏺ 15:19:16 ~/Dev/sandbox $ python main.py  

Creating table ExampleTable...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    db_client = MyDbClient()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/main.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.create_table()
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/moto/core/models.py", line 122, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/main.py", line 27, in create_table
    self.dynamodb.create_table(**table_params)
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 569, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1005, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1029, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 196, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 105, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 188, in sign
    auth = self.get_auth_instance(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 306, in get_auth_instance
    frozen_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 634, in get_frozen_credentials
    self._refresh()
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 522, in _refresh
    self._protected_refresh(is_mandatory=is_mandatory_refresh)
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 538, in _protected_refresh
    metadata = self._refresh_using()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 685, in fetch_credentials
    return self._get_cached_credentials()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 695, in _get_cached_credentials
    response = self._get_credentials()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 2160, in _get_credentials
    response = client.get_role_credentials(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 569, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jovan/Dev/sandbox/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1023, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the GetRoleCredentials operation: Not yet implemented

Another thing that I have tried is to individually wrap the __init__, put_item_in_table and get_item_from_table with the @mock_aws decorator, however that does NOT work, since in that case the the aws mock environment is created anew every time any of those functions is called, and therefore the created dynamo table does not persist between invocations (which is the complete opposite of what I need)
If possible I would like to just rely on the boto3 and moto libraries. I know that aws localstack exists as a tool, but that is overkill for what I am trying to achieve and I would like to not use it

It sounds like the system has SSO-based credentials configured. All requests to AWS are intercepted, Moto just doesn't know how to respond to the SSO auth request.
Two workarounds for that:

Disable the SSO-based credentials completely (for example by renaming ~/.aws/credentials to something else)
Explicitly call this script with custom credentials:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test pytest main`

That should override the SSO-based credentials that are configured on your system.
(FWIW - the code works on my machine! So it looks like you're pretty close.)

Is there a way to do that from within the code? I would like to keep my invocation as only python main and not affect the ~/.aws/credentials file

A bit ugly, but you could try to override the credentials before loading boto3?os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "test"; # same for secret; import boto3
